# Proving $f(x)$ is onto using maxima/minima

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity, maxima-minima

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function defined from $f(x):R\to{A}$, where $A$ is a bounded closed interval. If I can prove that end points of $A$ are global maxima and global minima of $f(x)$, Is $f(x)$ always onto(surjective) or there are some exceptions?

Comment: Instead of *finite set* I assume you mean *bounded closed interval*?

Comment: Assuming Hagen is right in that you mean "bounded closed interval" and not "finite" (finite subsets of the reals are rarely interesting when doing analysis of functions), the intermediate value theorem will give you this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no exceptions, by the intermediate value theorem.